# Can i use Bootstrapping to style single pages within a web-app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I'm developing a web application, and I recently discovered the need of a basic input form. The rest of my application does not have much of this, mostly single input-fields. I figured I would try to use a javascript library for validation, and ended up choosing parsley.js.

[in this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3WZ6DKB8wg), the tutor uses bootstrapping, a term I have come across a lot lately, but have no experience with. I figured I'd try it out in the single page of my web app.

However I get errors on the first character of the css I try to import, stating that `<` is an illegal token. This is of course the start of the file `<!DOCTYPE html>`. So in other words, the .css is found and included, it is just not accepted. This error has been repeated with a couple of different import sources now.

I've tried to look a little outside the box, to figure out why. I read posts like these:

- [What is bootstrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254542/what-is-bootstrapping)
- [Setup bootstrup file in java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071985/setup-bootstrup-file-in-java-web-application?lq=1)

These have led me to suspect that bootstrapping might not be meant for importing a style sheet, for a single page which is only a part of a web app, like I am trying to do.

So, is it wrong to think that I can use bootstrapping as I would import a .css file, for a single page? If not, what else might my problem be?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to tell that I am importing the css and js libraries through their online url's. If i copy them to my workspace, and import them from there, I get this error:

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is 
exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

Comment: I think you've thoroughly confused bootstrapping the technique with Bootstrap the library. They have nothing to do with each other. I didn't watch the whole Youtube tutorial, but the only "bootstrapping" it seems to do is include Bootstrap (the library), and the questions you link to talk about bootstrapping (the technique).

Comment: Also, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do. If a file starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` it isn't a (valid) CSS file.

Comment: That first comment is very helpful. Yes, I most certainly have confused the two terms.

the two imports below returns files that start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

although I do get some warnings on MIME-types

Comment: By the way, you have already answered my original question. Although it builds on a misunderstanding on my side, maybe it can be helpful to others, so if you style an answer, explaining that bootstrap and bootstrapping are two very different things, and that one indeed can use bootstrap css to style only a single page, I'll accept it. Then I'll continue trying to figure out where that doctype html comes from, and why I get these errors. Thanks for crossing one option off my list of suspects.