# Proper way to include SPL Class Loader

Tags: php

#### Problem

I am using the [SPL Class Loader](https://gist.github.com/221634) provided by PSR Group. However, I've come to a chicken-egg paradox.

That is, this will autoload classes preventing explicitly including them. But I first need to `include`/`require` this class and the code for instantiating the object

```
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', '/path/to/doctrine');
$classLoader->register();
```

#### Question

What is common solution for including the autoloader code?

In the case of a front-end controller, I could add the code there. But I'm not always using the front-end controller patter. I suppose I could also use PHP's [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). Interested in the communities input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly require the autoloader on the bootstrap stage (the stage where the application is started up).

All subsequent functions/classes are then autoloaded.

Comment: Fine for an *app*. What if I just have a large codebase, with multiple entry points (e.g. APIs)?

Comment: Are you seriously saying that you *don't* have a bootstrap or init file for your application?  Do you have all of your init logic spread across all of your entry points?  Fix that.

Comment: @Charles, no that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: While this didn't thoroughly answer *my* question, it is the general approach. If you're not familiar with *"bootstrap"*, read [what is bootstrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254542/what-is-bootstrapping).