# What does bootstrap mean in an angular js tutorial?

Tags: angularjs

The tutorial keeps referencing the term bootstrapping but when I search the term I see a link to a framework by twitter. Are they talking about something specific like this or something more general?

Comment: Could you link the tutorial you're reading?  It could have a couple meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general term. This is a top definition see the following

> A technique of loading a program into a computer by means of a few
>   initial instructions that enable the introduction of the rest of the
>   program from an input device.

In short its a way to start by loading the outline of a set of a program and it will then pull in the other dependencies to get you started with that program/framework (in your case an angularjs project).

And no i looked at the google documentation (unless your looking at codeschool and they dont seem to be referring to twitters bootstrap at all).

[This question seems to discuss it in thorough detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254542/what-is-bootstrapping) the definition stems from "pulling one up by their bootstraps"

Answer (score 2):

In a very simple term you can understand it as initializing, or starting, your Angular app.

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) says

> In general parlance, bootstrapping usually refers to the starting of a
>   self-sustaining process that is supposed to proceed without external
>   input. In computer technology the term (usually shortened to booting)
>   usually refers to the process of loading the basic software into the
>   memory of a computer after power-on or general reset, especially the
>   operating system which will then take care of loading other software
>   as needed.
>   ........
>
> "A different use of the term bootstrapping is to use a compiler to
>   compile itself, by first writing a small part of a compiler of a new
>   programming language in an existing language to compile more programs
>   of the new compiler written in the new language."

The below image from the [Bootstrap docs of AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) will make it clear.

[image]