# Run a script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a script during my building process in my `Dockerfile`, but it doesn't seems to work.

I tried that way:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
ADD bootstrap.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/bootstrap.sh"]
```

Also this way:

```
FROM php:7-fpm    
ADD bootstrap.sh /
RUN bash -c "/bootstrap.sh"
```

And also by executing my running container:

```
docker exec symfony /bin/bash -c "/bootstrap.sh"
```

Nothing seems to work.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Does `bootstarp.sh` have the executable bit set?

Comment: Like that RUN chmod +x /bootstarp.sh ?

Comment: With "does not work", what exactly is happening? Does it show an error? Is the file present inside the image? If you `docker exec -it symfony bash` inside the container, can you manually run the script, and check its contents? (`cat bootstarp.sh`)?

Comment: try this: `docker exec symfony /bin/bash /bootstarp.sh` and let me know the output.

Comment: Ermahgerd bootstarp!

Comment: Sometimes it can help to use the absolute path instead of relative path for the script, for example `"/bootstrap.sh"` --> `<absolute path>/bootstrap.sh`

Answer (score 217, accepted):

`RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT` are two different ways to execute a script.

`RUN` means it creates an intermediate container, runs the script and freeze the new state of that container in a new intermediate image. The script won't be run after that: your final image is supposed to reflect the result of that script.

`ENTRYPOINT` means your image (which has not executed the script yet) will create a container, and runs that script.

In both cases, the script needs to be added, and a `RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh` is a good idea.

It should also start with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (like `#!/bin/sh`)

Considering your script (`bootstrap.sh`: a couple of `git config --global` commands), it would be best to `RUN` that script once in your `Dockerfile`, but making sure to use the right user (the global `git config` file is `%HOME%/.gitconfig`, which by default is the `/root` one)

Add to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN /bootstrap.sh
```

Then, when running a container, check the content of `/root/.gitconfig` to confirm the script was run.

Comment: Also, you might have meant `bootstrap.sh` instead of `bootstarp.sh`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1254561/6309

Comment: The shebang on the first line did it for me, thanks! :)

Comment: Please check out of the box docker image - https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/myset/bootstrap

Comment: @myset Interesting idea: executing `$BOOTSTRAP`, with that variable being set at runtime to what you want to execute.

Answer (score 60):

In addition to the answers above:

**If you created/edited your .sh script file in Windows, make sure it was saved with line ending in Unix format**. By default many editors in Windows will convert Unix line endings to Windows format and Linux will not recognize shebang (#!/bin/sh) at the beginning of the file. So Linux will produce the error message like if there is no shebang.

Tips:

- If you use Notepad++, you need to click "Edit/EOL Conversion/UNIX (LF)"
- If you use Visual Studio, I would suggest installing "[End Of Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rolfwr.EndoftheLine)" plugin.
  Then you can make line endings visible by pressing Ctrl-R, Ctrl-W. And to set Linux style endings you can press Ctrl-R, Ctrl-L. For Windows style, press Ctrl-R, Ctrl-C.

Comment: My VSCode had automatically set a shell script's lined endings to CRLF in windows. The docker build was failing because of some random characters.

I changed the settings in VS Code and it immediately started to work. Thanks! I've upvoted.

Comment: on Windows git checks out by default with CR+LF, and this causes the issue for shell scripts when docker image is created, so your answer is really helpful!

Comment: Tip: Better give an extension to the scripts you are going to run from docker (e.g. `.sh`) and add a `.gitattributes` file to your `git` repo root with the following content: `*.sh text eol=lf`. Then you don't need to worry about newlines.

Comment: @MarinosAn , good advice, though it will not stop a text editor placing wrong ending when you edit the file. But, I agree, it is good to have that git setting anyway.

Answer (score 28):

Try to create script with `ADD` command and specification of working directory
Like this("script" is the name of script and `/root/script.sh` is where you want it in the container, it can be different path:

```
ADD script.sh /root/script.sh
```

In this case `ADD` has to come before `CMD`, if you have one
BTW it's cool way to import scripts to any location in container from host machine

In `CMD` place `[./script]`

It should automatically execute your script

You can also specify `WORKDIR` as `/root`, then you'l be automatically placed in root, upon starting a container

Comment: How does docker indentify where script.sh is at first? I mean, the first parameter, `script.sh`

Comment: since you're building container, you also in charge of placing paths

Comment: the path and name of the first param `script.sh` is relative to the `Dockerfile`

Comment: @eja it seems not: "source needs to be within the directory where the docker build command was run."

Answer (score 23):

It's best practice to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` when you're copying from the local file system to the image. Also, I'd recommend creating a sub-folder to place your content into. If nothing else, it keeps things tidy. Make sure you mark the script as executable using `chmod`.

Here, I am creating a `scripts` sub-folder to place my script into and run it from:

```
RUN mkdir -p /scripts
COPY script.sh /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts
RUN chmod +x script.sh
RUN ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

For running a bash script when during container creation:

Make `script.sh` file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
you commands
```

If you are using windows, you must change `script.sh` file convention.
To do this, in Notepad++, go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Change from CRLF to LF, and your bash file will be valid for execution.

If you are using an Alpine image, you must use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of your bash file.

Then, in your Dockerfile, copy your bash file to your image, and use the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction for running the file when container is being created:

```
COPY script.sh /
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]
```

Notice that the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction uses the location of the bash file you copied into your image.

now when you create a container, `script.sh` file will execute.

Comment: "notice: if you are using an alpine image, you must use #!/bin/sh`` instead of #!/bin/bash``` in the first line of your bash file.".

Nice catch. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```sh
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY bootstrap.sh .
RUN ./bootstrap.sh
```